# THREEJS display an object3D in front of a 360 stereo video sphere

Tags: three.js, webvr, 360-virtual-reality, 360-panorama

Hi i'm working on a vr project with threejs and an oculus rift.
I made a 24 meters wide 360 stereoscopic video
but when i try to display some text in front of it
i have some strange trouble vision effect or kind of eye separation issue.
if anyone has an idea... thanks :/

Answer (score 0):

The text must always be closer than anything it obstructs on the video for this to work. That is, if the 360 cameras took images with nothing closer than 1.5 meters, the text should be at around 1.2 meter.
Disabling the head movement effect on the text will help too (keep the rotation, just disable the translation).

And 24 meters is a bit low, try a few hundred, maybe a kilometer. Remember that the video must look like it's in the infinite range and both head movement and IPD must be completely ignorable.